# onRowMouseOver not triggering in react-bootstrap-table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

My table is:

```
    <BootstrapTable options={this.state.tableOptions} className="animated fadeIn" data={opportunities} striped hover condensed>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='ticker' dataSort={true} dataFormat={this.symbolFormatter} dataAlign='center'>Symbol</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='symbol' dataFormat={this.strategyFormatter} className="clearfix" dataSort={true} dataAlign='center'>Strategy</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='probability' dataFormat={this.percentFormatter} dataSort={true} dataAlign='center'>Probabilty</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='shamoonRank' dataFormat={this.progressFormatter} dataAlign='center' dataSort={true}>Should I Do It?</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='spread' dataFormat={this.currencyFormatter} dataAlign='center' dataSort={true}>Spread</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='maxLoss' dataFormat={this.currencyFormatter} dataAlign='center' dataSort={true}>Max Loss</TableHeaderColumn>
    </BootstrapTable>
```

My options looks like:

```
this.state = {
  animatedClass: 'hidden',
  opportunityId: null,
  tableOptions: {
    defaultSortOrder: 'desc',
    onRowMouseOver: (row) => {
      console.log('row')
    }
  }
}
```

As per the docs for [react-bootstrap-table](https://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#onRowMouseOver), if I mouse over, the function should get triggered. It does not. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I ran your sample code and it appeared to work for me. If you remove your table options from component state and just put them inside your render method does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the below to check the functionality,

```
   this.state = {
          console.log('state called')
      animatedClass: 'hidden',
      opportunityId: null,
      tableOptions: {
        defaultSortOrder: 'desc',
        onRowMouseOver: (row) => {
          console.log('row')
        }
      }
    }
```

If the log didn't get worked try to remove the TableHeaderColumn and use simple table and try to trigger.
It worked for me